# Starting point of Azure WebApp

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I opened a new .Net Framework WebApp and I am using it with Azure.

At the very first point, when I run the App from Visual Studio, it opens the browser and shows the default page:

[image]

I was looking for a "main" class or method but could not find one. I am wondering where does it start from? how this thing works?

If added a new method for which I want to run together with the WebApp, where should I call it from ?

Comment: You need to provide more info but if you want to learn the best place is the Microsoft docs https://learn.microsoft.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering where does it start from? how this thing works?

This is about how does asp.net webapp run.**When the application starts up, it runs Global.asax’s Application_Start() method.** In this method, you can add Route objects to the static `RouteTable.Routes` collection. These will be inspected later when each request is received. Each Route object defines a URL pattern to be matched and the controller to be used in this case.

For more detail about how the Asp.net webapp run, you could refer to this [article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2007/11/20/aspnet-mvc-pipeline-lifecycle/) and this [one](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/mvc-architecture-its-pipeline4/).

> If added a new method for which I want to run together with the WebApp, where should I call it from ?

When you publish to azure and add a new method in a controller, you could call it like `yourappname.azurewebsites.net/Controllername/methodname`. It mainly depend on your `Rounte`, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-controller).

**[Azure App Service Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-overview)** is a service for hosting web applications, REST APIs, and mobile back ends. You can develop in your favorite language, be it .NET, .NET Core, Java, Ruby, Node.js, PHP, or Python. Applications run and scale with ease on Windows-based environments.

With App Service, you **pay for the Azure compute resources you use**. The compute resources you use is determined by the `App Service plan` that you run your Web Apps on.